# Change divs width/height dinamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Hi stackoverflow community! I'm making some practice with css/html5 "copying" other websites layouts and stuff to learn and understand how things works.

Now I'm get into this website codepen.io/picks/10/ where the divs after "Picked Pens" change their size dinamically if i resize my browser. So my question is: what is the "magic" behind this thing? 
I'm not looking for any code but just some stuff to study to understand how this kind of things works.

Comment: You are looking for `responsive website layouts`. This is a huge topic by itself and not an simple answer here. So I will flag this question as too broad.

Comment: I recommend you to learn media queries

Comment: Well i was just looking for a explanation. Thank you esbenhr ...

Ah i'll take a look to this things so :D Thank you dulaj sanjaya!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know two ways:

1- [Bootstrap column-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068127/bootstrap-responsive-column-layout-stacking-columns)

2- [Media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the answer victor, im going to take a look at mediaqueries :D